# How to get Future callback in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

Good day. I am a flutter beginner and now do some simple pratice.

I want: Press a button and call login api, if api response is success then go to main page.

but I don't know how to get callback result.

viewModel

```
  Future<String> login(String account, String password) async {
    try {
      futureLogin = logon(account, password);
        await futureLogin.then((value) {

          print("key=${value.data.key}");//success print correct key

          return value.data.key;

        }).catchError((error) {
          print("error=$error");
        });
    } catch (error) {}

    return "";
  }
```

Button click event

```
onPressed: () async {
    var result = await viewModel.login(account, password);
    print("result=${result}");//print ""
}
```

I think that I can simply use `await` keyword to get my api result but not works.

How to solve it.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: what not works?  why do you catch any error and not use it in any way?

Comment: @pskink In button `onPressed` I want to print key but print ""

Comment: What is futureLogin?

Comment: @pskink Catch Error can ignore here that is not my question.

Comment: @JustaPerson A `async` function call login api

Comment: try checking the runtime type of futureLogin and see if the value returned is correct.

Comment: @JustaPerson Yes it can print correct key but I don't know how to callback to `onPressed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using async await :

```
Future<String> login(String account, String password) async {
    try {
      futureLogin = logon(account, password);
      var value = await futureLogin;
      return value.data.key;
    } catch (error) {
        return "";
    }
  }
```

or using .then function add return key after calling futureLogin

```
return await futureLogin.then(......);
```

Comment: FYI, one of [your avatar versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCZt2.jpg?s=32&g=1) is broken, it's a [common and known imgur bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166575/why-is-there-a-peeking-duck-in-my-profile-pic), can you please re-upload your avatar so it would be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you in return is not from the **login** function but from **then** function and this result nobody use. After this you make return with empty string
Change your code to

```
   Future<String> login(String account, String password) async {
       try {
           final result = await logon(account, password);
           print("key=${result.data.key}");//success print correct key
           return data.key;
       } catch (error) {
           print("error=$error");
       }

       return "";
   }
```

Comment: How to return `value.data.key`

Comment: Let's go line by line:
1-` final result = await logon(account, password);` - awaiting result from logon function
2- `print("key=...)` - print key value
3- `return data.key;` - return key value
4- `print("error=$error");` - print error if happen due logon function
5- `return "";` -  return empty string if error happen